# Linear complexity of powers of a periodic sequences over finite fields

Tags: sequences-and-series, finite-fields, coding-theory

Let $\mathbf{a}^N = a_0 a_1\cdots a_{N-1}$ and let $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{a}^N\mathbf{a}^N \cdots $ be an $N$-periodic sequence over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q$ elements, where $N \mid (q-1)$. Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$. If the linear complexity of $\mathbf{a}$ is $L$, what is the linear complexity of the sequence $\mathbf{a}_m = a_0^m a_1^m \cdots a_{N-1}^m a_0^m a_1^m \cdots$?

I know that for periodic sequences one may invoke for instance Blahut's theorem to obtain the linear complexity by looking at the Hamming weight of its DFT. However the DFT of powers of sequences, such as $\mathbf{a}_m$, is an $m$-th self-convolution, for which it is not clear to me its Hamming weight (i.e., the size of its support). Thus I wonder if there's some other way to obtain the linear complexity here?

Comment: This is likely tough in general - at least at the first sight.Hopefully more can be said in some interesting special cases. Undoubtedly you know of the upper bound $\binom L m$ for the linear complexity of the sequence $\mathbf{a}_m$. This can be achieved, if $N$ is large enough in comparison, and the sequence has a suitable structure. I don't know of another way of calculating the linear complexity. I do suspect that in many a case you can analyze the collisions among products of $m$ zeros of the feedback polynomial, and get a significantly better bound.

Comment: Thanks Jyrki. Yes I also believe this should be hard in general since it is related to how many elements are there in addition of sets, due to the nature of convolution. The upper bound you give I believe is by Key or consequences of his bound.